# Arquillian Test POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment <<jarname>>.jar

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss7.x, dao, jboss-arquillian

I have created few test from my EJBs in Arquillian. 2 tests passed so far. Unfortunately 3rd test fails with weird information which I have trouble to track.

```
13:16:51,206 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."test4.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test4.jar".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "test4.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class com.group7.service.NetworkService with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.test4.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/group7/daoInterface/NetworkDAOLocal;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1811) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.group7.daoInterface.NetworkDAOLocal from [Module "deployment.test4.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 15 more

13:16:51,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 3) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "test4.jar" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test4.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"test4.jar\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"test4.jar\""}}
13:16:51,228 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment test4.jar in 7ms
13:16:51,229 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 3) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."test4.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test4.jar".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "test4.jar"

13:16:51,281 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment arquillian-service in 6ms
13:16:51,306 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS014901: Content removed from location /home/bmj/Java/jboss_7.1/standalone/data/content/f0/d4d08224b3f1a188bb5d596eec8a15b971ec45/content
13:16:51,307 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) JBAS018558: Undeployed "arquillian-service"
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. As I said my 2 previous tests passed with no problems.

**NetworkServiceEJBTest.java**

```
package com.group7.service;


import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import javax.ejb.EJB;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.group7.daoInterface.NetworkDAOLocal;
import com.group7.entities.Network;
import com.group7.entities.NetworkId;
import com.group7.serviceInterface.NetworkServiceLocal;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class NetworkServiceEJBTest {

        @Deployment
        public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
            return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test4.jar")
                    .addClasses(Network.class, NetworkId.class, NetworkService.class, NetworkServiceLocal.class)
                    .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml")
                    .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

      }

        @EJB
        private NetworkDAOLocal dao;


        @Test
        public void isNetworkTableEmpty() throws Exception {

            assertFalse(dao.getAllNetworkInfo().isEmpty()); 
//          assertEquals(dao.getAllNetworkInfo().size(), 1);
        }
}
```

**Network.java** (entity)

```
package com.group7.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * 
 * @author marc
 *
 */
@Entity
@IdClass(NetworkId.class)
@Table(name="Network")
public class Network implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MCC")
    private int mcc;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MNC")
    private int mnc;

    @Column(name = "Country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "Operator")
    private String operator;

    //Getters and setters
    public int getMcc() {
        return mcc;
    }
    public void setMcc(int mcc) {
        this.mcc = mcc;
    }
    public int getMnc() {
        return mnc;
    }
    public void setMnc(int mnc) {
        this.mnc = mnc;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }
    public void setOperator(String operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }


}
```

**NetworkDaoImpl.java** (network dao)

```
package com.group7.dao;

import java.util.Collection;

@Stateless
@Local
public class NetworkDAOImple implements NetworkDAOLocal{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    public Collection<Network> getAllNetworkInfo() {
        Query q = em.createQuery("from Network");
        return q.getResultList();
    }

}
```

**NetworkDAOLocal.java** ( dao interface)

```
package com.group7.daoInterface;

import java.util.Collection;

@Local
public interface NetworkDAOLocal {

    Collection<Network> getAllNetworkInfo();

}
```

**arquillian.xml**

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <container qualifier="jbossas-managed-wildfly-8" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="jbossHome">/home/bmj/Java/jboss_7.1</property>

        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.group7.theramones</groupId>
    <artifactId>TeamProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-jbossas-embedded</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                    <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.0.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.4</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-jbossas-managed</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error your posted is pretty clear, it can't find `NetworkDaoLocal` in your JAR.  Even the deployment you shared is not including it, instead including `NetworkServiceLocal`

Comment: Thanks. I have just realized how I was wrong. I should read caused by messages.I was reading first line of the Error message and try to follow this path.